# Sorting blocks of data based on a particular row of data

Tags: sort

I was given the below script by this great community to sort the rows of information.

> BEGIN {
>
> > FS=":"
> >      PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc";
> >     }
>
> /./ {
>     values[$1]=$0
>   }
>
> > /^$/ {
> >       asort(values)
> >       for (element in values)
> >         print values[element]
> >       print ""
> >       delete values
> >     }
>
> END {
>
> > asort(values)
> >       for (element in values)
> >       print values[element]
> >     }

Each block are sorted alphabetically, which is working as originally intended (shown below).  Now I am asked to sort all these blocks of data (each block of data has a physical space between each other) based on the sessionStartTime.  I think this is going to be alot harder since each 8-line block needs to stick together.

> cabLoginID:0557CAWG0FP27K31JG7Q
>   loginName:john
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
>   session:cabSessionID:05P2R3PJGKG2Y2XE4NCZ
>   **sessionStartTime:2018-10-18T13:03:00.973Z**
>
>   totalJSHeapSize:36675584
>   usedJSHeapSize:29721040
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
>
> cabLoginID:05P4X6K6GFPJ7K31EJ7H
>   loginName:bob
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
>   session:cabSessionID:0536XLJPG7BJXRN42A0F
>   **sessionStartTime:2018-10-11T11:37:28.195Z**
>
>   totalJSHeapSize:54501376
>   usedJSHeapSize:35478968
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
>
> cabLoginID:053XCDTF8D4J6PD3BG8P
>   loginName:jack
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2217857988
>   session:cabSessionID:052FPBP6Q6X2XGERWHBT
>   **sessionStartTime:2018-10-01T01:04:10.899Z**
>
>   totalJSHeapSize:42358792
>   usedJSHeapSize:36482584
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0

Desired result:

> cabLoginID:053XCDTF8D4J6PD3BG8P
>   loginName:jack
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2217857988
>   session:cabSessionID:052FPBP6Q6X2XGERWHBT
>   **sessionStartTime:2018-10-01T01:04:10.899Z**
>
>   totalJSHeapSize:42358792
>   usedJSHeapSize:36482584
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
>
> cabLoginID:05P4X6K6GFPJ7K31EJ7H
>   loginName:bob
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
>   session:cabSessionID:0536XLJPG7BJXRN42A0F
>   **sessionStartTime:2018-10-11T11:37:28.195Z**
>
>   totalJSHeapSize:54501376
>   usedJSHeapSize:35478968
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0
>
> cabLoginID:0557CAWG0FP27K31JG7Q
>   loginName:john
>   memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:2181038080
>   session:cabSessionID:05P2R3PJGKG2Y2XE4NCZ
>   **sessionStartTime:2018-10-18T13:03:00.973Z**
>
>   totalJSHeapSize:36675584
>   usedJSHeapSize:29721040
>   userAgent:Mozilla/5.0

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the timestamps sort lexically in your locale, and given GNU Awk version 4.0 or later:

```
gawk -vRS= '
  match($0,/sessionStartTime:([^[:space:]]*)/,m) {
    a[m[1]] = $0
  } 
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" 
    for (i in a) print a[i] "\n"
  }' file
```

---

Similar approach in Perl:

```
perl -00 -lne '
  $h{$1} = $_ if /sessionStartTime:(\S*)/
  }{
  for $k (sort keys %h) {print $h{$k}}
' file
```

Comment: Much more elegant than my `perl` hack.

Comment: @steve thanks - I've attempted a perl implementation of the same approach

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick.  I'll try post a more readable version shortly.

```
$ perl -e 'while(<>){next if /^$/;push @a,$_;if(/sessionStartTime/){$k=$_}if($#a==7){$v{$k}=[@a];undef @a}}for $x(sort keys %v){for $i (0..7){print $v{$x}[$i]}print "\n"}' <input >output
```

Cleaner, more readable version.  Functionally identical.

```
perl -e 'while(<>) {
             # skip any blank lines
             next if /^$/;

             # add line to array a
             push @a,$_;

             # if line holds our key value, store it 
             if(/sessionStartTime/) {
                 $k=$_;
             }

             # if we've got all 8 lines, store it in a hash, keyed on our sessionStartTime
             if($#a==7) {
                 $v{$k}=[@a];
                 undef @a;
             }
         }
         # After reaching end of file, process each key and print its 8 lines
         for $x (sort keys %v) {
             for $i (0..7) {
                 print $v{$x}[$i];
             }
             print "\n";
         }' <input  >output
```

Comment: Hi steve, I place your codes into a file, and put in the input and output.  When I tried to run the script, I am getting syntax errors getting the following-  First error:  d:\Logs\UserLogs\Commands>PerlSort.pl
Can't modify subtraction (-) in scalar assignment at D:\Logs\UserLogs\Commands\PerlSort.pl line 2, near "perl -e 'while"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line '' string starting on line 1)  Second error: syntax error at D:\Logs\UserLogs\Commands\PerlSort.pl line 2, near ") {"  Third error: syntax error at D:\Logs\UserLogs\Commands\PerlSort.pl line 19, near "}"

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
declare -a LINES
declare -A BLOCKS

IFS=$'\n'

addToBlocks() {
  if [ "$EPOCH" ]
  then
    BLOCKS["$EPOCH"]="${LINES[*]}"
  else
    echo "No sessionStartTime line for this block."
  fi
}

while read LINE
do
  SSTIME="${LINE/sessionStartTime:}"
  [ "${SSTIME}" != "$LINE" ] && EPOCH="$( date +%s -d "${SSTIME%Z}" )"
  if [ "${LINE// }" == "" ]
  then
    addToBlocks
    LINES=()
    EPOCH=""
  else
    LINES+=("${LINE}")
  fi
done
addToBlocks

for TIME in $( echo "${!BLOCKS[*]}" | sort -n )
do
  echo "${BLOCKS[$TIME]}"
  echo
done
```

Same basic idea - bath the lines up till you reach a blank line, at which point save it in a hash keyed by datetime.  Once all rows are consumed, output all the blocks ordered by hash key.